# How to use a 'Container View' in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller, container-view

I have noticed the UI Component in XCode: `Container View`.

[image]

Based on the description provided I would like to make use of it to display a reusable component of my app in several different screens. I have been looking around online to try and find a basic tutorial or some documentation on it, however I havent found anything of use.

Please could someone advise on how to wire this up and make use of it? At the moment it also appears that the `container view` doesn't seem to resize which is problematic. Any tips on how to enable this would be appreciated too.

Cheers.

Comment: FULL SIMPLE TUTORIAL: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23403979/294884

Answer (score 63):

Well let's break this into some simple steps:

1. Drag a container view to the main view of one of your controllers. When you drag the container view, IB will create an embed segue for you and you can resize the container's view by dragging the resize control points as usual. Any changes in the size will be automatically reflected to the view that the segue is pointing to. The idea is that this view will be managed by a different controller, the embedded one.
   [image]
2. Set your custom subclass as the class of the embedded controller.
   [image]
3. Now you're good to go. Note that any containers you add will be available through the `childViewControllers` property on your main controller.
   [image]

This is obviously an oversimplified workflow but it's enough to get you started. For more information on the subject, [see Apple's documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html).

Comment: Great explanation! Link needs to be updated to Apple Documentation.

Comment: totally up-to-date guide for 2017 here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23403979/294884