# How to add a UIViewController/UITabBar to a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitabbar

I would like to add a custom `UITabBar` implementation to a `UITableViewCell`.

If a `UITableViewCell` was itself a `UIViewController` I could use view controller containment, but it isn't.

The best I can do right now is add the `TabBar's` view to the `contentView` of the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

    NSString *cellID;
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    cellID = @"TabCell";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID] ?: [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];

    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor;

    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    UIViewController *vc1 = [UIViewController new];
    vc1.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.magentaColor;
    vc1.title = @"TAB1";

    UIViewController *vc2 = [UIViewController new];
    vc2.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor;
    vc2.title = @"TAB2";

    tabBarController.delegate = self;
    tabBarController.viewControllers = @[vc1, vc2];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:tabBarController.view];

    return cell
}
```

The problem is that the cell only shows the view of the `TabBar` and not the `TabBar` control itself.

How can I show the entire `TabBar` in a `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of what the cell looks like now

Comment: The notion of putting a view controller in a table view cell makes me nervous. Can you tell us about what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Container View, which allows you to include a child View Controller. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16884879/how-to-use-a-container-view-in-ios) another SO post with instructions on how to do that.

But I have to agree with what @rikkigibson said on the comments, perhaps you should reconsider your approach. Maybe we can help if you share more details on what you want to accomplish.