# IBAction while using addChildViewController not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, menu, parent-child

I am making sample project to implement top menu.

Below is the project structure.

[image]

TopMenu is the parent view with structure shown below.

[image]

In TopViewController, viewDidLoad below is what I have.

```
NSString *whereToGo = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"whereToGo"]; // this is DarkGray by default
UIViewController *goToViewController;
goToViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:whereToGo];
goToViewController.view.frame = bottomView.bounds;
// bottomView is the first view (will bring child here)
[bottomView addSubview:goToViewController.view];
[self addChildViewController:goToViewController];
[goToViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Now when I execute project, I see Dark Gray, but when I click on `Click Me` button, nothing occurs (IBAction is not getting invoked).

```
- (IBAction)clickme:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"clickme==dark gray");
}
```

***What I was expecting is*** *when I click Click Me, I will see clickme==dark gray in log.*

Any reason why this is happening?

### [Sample project for download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bgbgwjvyx36du0y/TopMenuTest.zip?dl=0)

---

### Answer

As stated by MidhunMP, short answer is

**menuView was hiding bottomView**

Actually, for menuView I had backgroundColor as clearColor. And I assumed (which was wrong), as menuView is clear, touches won't work on menuView and those touches will go to bottomView.

Comment: Pls clarify what you expect by pressing "clickme"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is simple, you are adding the `goToViewController.view` to `bottomView`.

The `menuView` is on top of `bottomView`, so it hides the touches to the `goToViewController.view`. You need to add the `goToViewController.view` to the topmost view, aka `menuView`.

Now your view hierarchy is like:

```
bottomView -> goToViewController.view -> menuView
```

You need to change that to:

```
bottomView -> menuView -> goToViewController.view
```

Change you code to following and check:

```
NSString *whereToGo = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"whereToGo"]; // this is DarkGray by default
UIViewController *goToViewController;
goToViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:whereToGo];
goToViewController.view.frame = menuView.bounds;
[menuView addSubview:goToViewController.view];
[self addChildViewController:goToViewController];
[goToViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: All is well now, the issue was frame for my menu view was incorrect.. when I change to `menuView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 150);` all works great...

Comment: @FahimParkar: If you need to load view controllers to the first ViewController. It's better to use ContainerView, a suggestion. :)

Comment: do you mean in TopMenu? Can you elaborate more what I would need to do?

Comment: @FahimParkar: Can you check [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16884879/how-to-use-a-container-view-in-ios),[2](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html),[3](http://mobileoop.com/how-to-use-container-view-controller)

Answer (score 1):

The view you are using as a container is covered by other views.

Comment: I am not using Auto-Layout. I hate auto-layout.