# Swift popover in scrollview

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, scrollview, popover

i have a scrollview with some subviews. Inside this subviews i have other subviews.

i want to present a popover that is anchored to one of this "nested" subviews.

I correctly show the popover, and it is anchored to the corrected subview, but whenever i scroll the scrollview, the popover doesn't move with the scrollview. 
I would like my popover to move and to adjust its "x" origin every time i scroll the scrollview horizontally.

This is the code i use to present the popover.

```
func showAlarmViewController(notification: NSNotification){

    troubleViewController = TroubleshootViewController()
    troubleViewController!.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    troubleViewController!.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(300.0, 150.0)

    popoverMenuViewController = troubleViewController!.popoverPresentationController
    popoverMenuViewController!.permittedArrowDirections = .Down
    popoverMenuViewController!.delegate = self
    popoverMenuViewController!.passthroughViews = [self.detailScrollView]
    popoverMenuViewController!.sourceView = (notification.object as! UIView).superview
    popoverMenuViewController!.sourceRect = CGRect(x: -100, y: 100, width: 300, height: 150)

    presentViewController(
        troubleViewController!,
        animated: true,
        completion: nil)

}
```

any help please? 
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your popoverMenuViewController in one of the nested subviews of scrollview or in scrollview by

```
scrollview.addsubview(popoverMenuViewController)
```

If popoverMenuViewController controller is UIViewController, then add container view in scrollview and link that container view to popoverMenuViewController. later you can add container view as a subview of scrollview.

here, is the link how container view can be implemented. [How to use a 'Container View' in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16884879/how-to-use-a-container-view-in-ios)
And
http://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/07/21/ios-container-views/

or add popoverMenuViewController in one of the nested subview of scrollview

```
subviewofscrollview.addsubview(popoverMenuViewController)
```

Set your popoverMenuViewController anchor according to the subview content size, where you added this popoverMenuViewController.

Comment: popoverMenuViewController is a UIPopoverPresentationController, i can't add it as a subview.

Comment: I edited the code and given some links how you can use container view.

Comment: i understand, but can't i use the native "presentViewController" function? because i remember that i did this stuff in obj-c, but i don't remember how.. probably i did something in the scrollViewDidScroll method.. i would like to use the native popover because it automatically shows the popover in the correct position