# Resize view to account for toolbar

Tags: ios, uitoolbar

If I create a basic ViewController and add an opaque UIToolbar to the view, like so:

```
UIViewController* viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[viewController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]]; // To make it easy to see
self.window.rootViewController = viewController;

UIToolbar* toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, viewController.view.frame.size.height - 49, viewController.view.frame.size.width, 49)]; // At bottom. Height of 49
[toolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack]; // Opaque and easy to see

[self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:toolbar]; // Add toolbar to view controller
```

The view hierarchy ends up like below:

[image: View Controller behind Toolbar]

How do I make the View controller resize it's main area (the blue part) so it doesn't extend behind the UIToolbar?

Comment: just leave the viewController.view as is without setting color, add another UIView for blue part

Comment: Would this be the same as adding the view from another ViewController as a subview?

Comment: didn't get you @ ABeard

Comment: If I had a second View Controller called `secondVC`, would this be what you're suggesting?

`[viewController.view addSubview:secondVC.view];`

Comment: in that case you can use containers, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16884879/how-to-use-a-container-view-in-ios

Comment: I've tried adding my secondary ViewController as a child view of the main VC. But that didn't have any effect.
`[viewController addChildViewController:secondVC];
[secondVC didMoveToParentViewController:viewController];`

Unless I'm doing it wrong. This guide and most are for using IB.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27276561/adding-a-view-controller-as-a-subview-in-another-view-controller, verify your code with the accepted answer

Comment: My previous comment is mostly doing what they said. The only difference is they set the frame for the child VC.

If I set it to the frame of the parent VC, then it still extends behind the toolbar. If I don't set the frame, then it doesn't show up at all. If I have to calculate and set the frame, then it is not automatic.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line of code

```
viewController.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

this will make so view controller's edges are not extended in any direction.

Or you can add this if you want to extend top, left and right, but not bottom.

```
viewController.edgesForExtendedLayout =  UIRectEdgeTop, UIRectEdgeLeft, UIRectEdgeRight;
```

Comment: Neither of these had any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
UIViewController* viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [viewController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]]; // To make it easy to see
    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;

UIToolbar* toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, viewController.view.frame.size.height - 49, viewController.view.frame.size.width, 49)]; // At bottom. Height of 49
[toolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack]; // Opaque and easy to see

SecondViewController* secondChildVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"someId"];
[secondChildVC.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[viewController addChildViewController:secondChildVC];
[secondChildVC didMoveToParentViewController:viewController];
secondChildVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,viewController.view.frame.size.width,viewController.view.frame.size.height - 49);
[viewController.view addSubview:secondChildVC.view];

[self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:toolbar];
```

Comment: Do I have to calculate the frame of the second VC?

`secondChildVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,viewController.view.frame.size.width,viewController.view.frame.size.height - 49);`

This kind of calculation is exactly what I don't want to do.

Comment: I want the main VC to automatically calculate the correct size for the second VC. Is there no way to do this?

Comment: In other words, I need the main VC to act like a UITabBarController or a UINavigationController. Both of those automatically resize the content area without needing to calculate it myself.

Comment: if you don't want to calculate frame, then you can use NSLayoutConstraints

Comment: I'm starting to think that, myself. I'm trying to follow this guide here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31651022/how-to-create-layout-constraints-programmatically

Comment: To add constraints this way, will I need to include the second VC?

Comment: but i think its better to do with storyboard and its very easy to set constraints using storyboard

Comment: I'd love to do it with storyboard. But I can't on this project. :(

Comment: Thanks for your help, by the way.